# iOS "resizableImageWithCapInsets: resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch" this image how to set capInsets?

Tags: ios, uiimage, stretch

I must ensure that the arrows do not stretch. So how should I set capInsets?

Please check this image:

[image]

Comment: How you want to resize your image Horizontal or Vertical?

Answer (score 1):

UIImage *originalImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimagename"];

```
//Either you can use this 
//UIImage *resizeImg = [originalImg resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(4, 50, 30, 50) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];

//or you can use this
UIImage *resizeImg = [originalImg resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(4, 214, 30, 55) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];

//Before resize
self.original_Imageview.image = originalImg;
//after resize
self.resized_Imageview.image = resizeImg;

You can use this code to set your image 
[This is output image][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJV9X.png
```